# What's the best way to post multiple forms of same model in this situation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to post multiple forms of the same model in one submission.

So, I have a model "Task" which has a name, a category and a property field. I have also a model named "Task Check" which has a task and a status. The purpose of task check is to save the status of one task, like "done" or "checked" as can be seen below:

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    property = models.ManyToManyField(Property)

class TaskCheck(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='nd', max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='task_check', blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    property_check = models.ForeignKey(Propertycheck)

class Propertycheck(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    next_visit = models.DateField()
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=25)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

As can be seen in the models above, a TaskCheck is related to One PropertyCheck, the purpose of the "PropertyCheck" is to save a set of taskchecks.

**Functional Example:**

Someone goes to a property to check if everything is ok, he adds a PropertyCheck and then the list of TaskCheck's of every Task related to that property.

My template looks like this:

```
{% for obj in task %}
{% if obj.category == cat %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="pname">{{ obj.name }}</label>
            {{ task_form.status }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="pname">Notes</label>
            {{ task_form.notes }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="pname">Image</label>
            {{ task_form.image }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've reached here, I already have the list of tasks that belong to a specific property:[image]

But now I've no idea about how can I submit all those taskscheck at once. Should it be done with formsets? Is there a proper way to do this? Should I change something on my template?

**views.py**

```
def add_propertycheck(request, property_pk):
    property_id = property_pk
    data = {'property':property_id}
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(property=property_pk)
    category = tasks.values('category').distinct()
    tasks_name = tasks.values('name')
    category = tasks.values('category').distinct()
    property_reference = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        taskform = TaskCheckForm(request.POST)
        for task in tasks:
            if form.is_valid():
                checkform = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('propertycheck:details', args=[pk]))
    else:
        taskform = TaskCheckForm()

    context = {
        'task_form':taskform,
        'title':"Add Property Check",
        'task':tasks,
        'reference':property_reference,
        'category':category,
    }
    return render(request, 'propertycheck/add-propertycheck.html', context)
```

Comment: This is what *formsets* are all about: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. I've followed your advice and I've changed my views. My question now is, I need to work with related models via a foreign key, so with formsets how can I iterate through another model? The thing is that I need my TaskCheck to go through all the Tasks related to a specific property. How can I achieve this? Should I use inline formsets or there is another way to do this?